# What is the "&^" operator in golang?

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

I can't really google the name AND NOT and get any useful results, what exactly is this operator, and how could I do this in a language like C? I checked the specification, and there is nothing helpful in there but a list that says it's `&^` (AND NOT).

Comment: In what context? `&^` isn't an operator on its own, but it might be something like `7 BITWISE-AND BITWISE-NEGATION(1)`

Comment: I saw it in there code [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b39329bff56abf35edc91537252782814a7a4f84/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go#L213), they use it for a utf8 decode thing

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The C equivalent of the Go expression `x &^ y` is just `x & ~y`.  That is literally "`x` AND (bitwise NOT of `y`)".

In the [arithmetic operators section of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) describes `&^` as a "bit clear" operation, which gives an idea of what you'd want to use it for.  As two separate operations, `~y` will convert each one bit to a zero, which will then clear the corresponding bit in `x`.  Each zero bit will be converted to a one, which will preserve the corresponding bit in `x`.

So if you think of `x | y` as a way to turn on certain bits of `x` based on a mask constant `y`, then `x &^ y` is doing the opposite and turns those same bits off.

Comment: This was a very clear explanation, especially with the use case.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks. Specially its comparison with | (OR) operator.

Comment: Great answer but "That is literally "x AND (bitwise NOT of y)" is not the same as "So if you think of x | y as a way to turn on certain bits of x based on a mask constant y, then x &^ y is doing the opposite and turns those same bits off." If you `1010 &^ 0011` using two statements above you would get different results. The "x AND (bitwise NOT of y)". is correct.

Comment: Basically that means, a bitclear b means, you use b as a bit sequence such that, you set 1 for the bits you need to clear on a. And you set 0 for the bits you want to have as is on a. b is used as the guide for the bitclear operation to show which bits you need to clear on a. To show which bit you need to clear you set 1 for the corresponding bit on b.

Answer (score 6):

> The &^ operator is bit clear (AND NOT): in the expression z = x &^ y,
> each bit of z is 0 if the corresponding bit of y is 1; otherwise it
> equals the corresponding bit of x.

From [The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io/)

**Example:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x uint8 = 0b00001111
    var y uint8 = 0b00000100
    var z uint8 = 0b00001011

    if x&^y == z {
        fmt.Printf("  ( x)         (%08b)\n", x)
        fmt.Printf("& (^y)       & (%08b)\n", ^y)
        fmt.Printf("------   =   ------------\n")
        fmt.Printf("  ( z)         (%08b)\n", x&^y)
    }
}
```

> **Result:**
>
> ```
>   ( x)         (00001111)
> & (^y)       & (11111011)
> ------   =   ------------
>   ( z)         (00001011)
> ```